# Can Raspberry Pi running Win10 IoT uses both Wifi and Bluetooth communication at the same time?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm still a beginner to programming. I have met some problem of my problem, where the pi couldnt use the wifi and bluetooth at the same time. This is because initially the code without the bluetooth element, it works fine. But when i added the bluetooth code into the program, it just went weird. It couldnt retrieve any data from the Firebase through Wifi. Is it really that they couldnt work together at the same time or it is wrong with the code. Is it because of the socketstream something like this? Really thanks for the help.

Link to the code as it is too long.

Comment: We can use both Wifi and Bluetooth communication at the same time.I have downloaded the provided code, but the code can not run. I'm not sure whether you use the Raspberry Pi as client or server for Bluetooth. You can refer this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat). Did you get any exception when running the code? You can also try to connect the bluetooth in device portal and run the code without bluetooth communication.

Comment: I dont get any exception during the debugging. Perhaps I added the exception handling when it needs to read, write data to the Firebase. So, when I run the code, it enters the exception event of that. Rpi will be the master. 

"You can also try to connect the bluetooth in device portal and run the code without bluetooth communication." For this one, meaning i just delete this line of code? 

deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                "System.ItemNameDisplay:~~\"HC-05\"",
                null,
                DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);

Comment: When I deploy the apps remotely to the Win10 IoT devices, the debugging shows "the network connection to... has been lost. Debugging will be aborted." So, I suspect that the wifi connection lost when this apps runs.

Comment: If possible could you please provide the sample project so that i can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure. You meant the full project file?

Comment: Yes. Because i can not reproduce the issue in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with your code. The app will get an exception as "Access is denied. ", it will cause the app crash. So you need to add try catch in the function `DeviceWatcher_Added` to ensure the app won't dump when the Bluetooth could not connect.

```
    private async void DeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        try
        {
            var device = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(args.Id);

            var services = await device.GetRfcommServicesAsync();
            if (services.Services.Count > 0)
            {
                var service = services.Services[0];

                stream = new StreamSocket();
                await stream.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName);

                rx = new DataReader(stream.InputStream);
                tx = new DataWriter(stream.OutputStream);

                await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                    Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    () => { Device_9.IsEnabled = true; });

                deviceWatcher.Stop();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

BTW, you may refer to the sample mentioned in my first comment, it shows how to connect the RfcommService to communicate with Bluetooth. Please note that, in the sample the server creates the RfcommServiceProvider by guid, and the client connects the server with RfcommService from this guid as uuid.

```
        var rfcommServices = await bluetoothDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(
            RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(Constants.RfcommChatServiceUuid), BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

Comment: Noted, however the apps still couldnt proceed with the retrieving data from Firebase. Regarding of the sample, I dont how to implement as I will need the communication which is automatically and required send and write function only.

Comment: @ChenL, so currently the problem is you can get the data from your Firebase? Did you check the permission of your Firebase?

Comment: Yes. I have checked that. I have recreated a simple apps to check on the same issue. Now this apps works normally on my PC, and when I deployed it to the raspberry pi, the system doesnt work. Here is the project file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18nhp4wniWlU2eSWoQfEwYl2ORgR2Ltyl

Comment: @ChenL, I have download the project,but it seems that the FireSharp package is not included in the project. I installed the FireSharp 2.0.4, in this build, use UpdateAsync instead of UpdateTaskAsync and GetAsync instead of GetTaskAsync. It works fine for me on my device. It is recommended that you need to check whether the obj is null before the code `dev1_status = obj.Dev_1;` because of the timeout of getting the object from Firebase. You need to check if the internet connection of the device can access the Firebase.

Comment: Thanks. I had changed the code and tried. It is still getting the same result. Perhaps any changes of the device settings should be made?

Comment: @ChenL, can you ping firebase on your device?It is using HTTPS protocol to get the data from firebase. Please confirm if there is some block in the route for the network.

Comment: Is there any example to do that ping?

Comment: @ChenL, you can connect to the device via [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/powershell),and then run the command `ping firebase.google.com`. Also you can open [Firebase Diagnostic Test Page](https://www.firebase.com/test.html) to check the connection.